# Jquery - How to set mouseleave event to an after() generating div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent, mouseleave

I use the function below to enlarge a div from the center. Cause the jQuery generating elements can't be access by jQuery again so I put `onmouseout` attribute to the generated `<div>`.But it occurs that when I move my mouse into the child elements of the div, the onmouseout event is triggered and that is not what I want.

So, how can I fix it or is there any other way to do the same effect?

```
shows = $(".shows");
shows.bind('mouseenter', function() {
    enlargeCenter($(this), 1.8, 'bigger');
});

function enlargeCenter(des, ratio, nclass) {
    var oWidth  = des.width();
    var oHeight = des.height();
    var nHeight = oHeight * ratio;
    var nWidth  = oWidth * ratio;
    var left    = des.position().left;
    var top     = des.position().top;
    left        = (oWidth - nWidth) / 2 - oWidth;
    top         = (oHeight - nHeight) /2;


    des.after("<div class='" + nclass + "' onmouseout='remove()'>" + des.html() + "</div>");
    $("." + nclass).css({
        'width': nWidth,
        'height': nHeight,
        'left': left,
        'top': top
    });
}
```

here are the css codes

```
.shows, .bigger {
    float:left;
width:200px;
height:250px;
position: relative;
left:0;
top:0;
border:1px #ccc solid;
background: RGB(245,245,245);
overflow:hidden;
}

.bigger {
border:0;
background: white;
box-shadow: #ccc 0 0 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: #ccc 0 0 5px;
-ms-box-shadow: #ccc 0 0 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #ccc 0 0 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="shows">
        <p>odfelakjfelkavjekvaelkfjjjj</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you move your mouse in that `<p>` the `onmouseout` event will be triggered and the bigger `div` will be remove.

Comment: use. on() or. live() depending on your jquery version

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Post your `html/css` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouseout event triggers as soon as your mouse leaves that target element or enters a child element.  IE has a proprietary mouseleave event that only gets triggered when the mouse leaves the target element entirely.  jQuery simulates this with the mouseleave function.  I tried the following change and it I think it will do what you want:

```
...
des.after("<div class='" + nclass + "'>" + des.html() + "</div>");
    $("." + nclass).css({
        'width': nWidth,
        'height': nHeight,
        'left': left,
        'top': top
    }).mouseleave(function(){$(this).remove()});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have anything to see, I'm guessing this might solve your problem,

Change your `mouseenter` event from,

```
shows.bind('mouseenter', function() {
    enlargeCenter($(this), 1.8, 'bigger');
});
```

to this,

```
shows.bind('mouseenter', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    enlargeCenter($(this), 1.8, 'bigger');
});
```